# How to return the data from a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have some function like this

```
function getIndex(name) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var index = 0;
    $("#dropDown option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() === name) {
            index = this.index + 1;
            deferred.resolveWith(this, {result: index });
            return deferred.promise();
        }
    });

    deferred.resolveWith(this, { result: index });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

And then I am calling the function like this:

```
getIndex("Hello World").done(function(result) {
alert (result);
});
```

However, the content of result is undefined.

Am I doing a wrong use of the deferred logic? What would be the right way then?

Comment: try to use `deferred.resolve` instead of `resolveWith`

Comment: Why are you using a promise? Promises are good for asynchronous logic, but there is nothing asynchronous in your code.

Comment: @abl Do you mean I can do var index = getIndex("Hellow World") and then do the alert(result) with no problem at all?

Comment: Yes, but the `getIndex` function can be simpler, and there's no need to use promises at all. [See this snippet](https://gist.github.com/delicious-roasted-turkey/0d1ff1b8e2782c028eeee7125375f22f)

Comment: is there really a deferred.resolveWith method. I never heard about that.

Answer (score -1):

Several "issues".

1. Irrespective of choosing to use [resolveWith](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/), its syntax takes an array as second argument, not an object.
2. There seems to be an attempt to get the index of every option that has matching text. Presenting options with the same text in a drop down may be unusual
3. The following modified code example resolves the deferred once , and shows how an array of values passed to the `resolve` method is passed as separate parameters to the `done` callback.

```js
    function getIndex(name) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var result = [];
        $("#dropDown option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == name) {
                result.push(this.index + 1);
            }
        });
        deferred.resolveWith(this, result);
        console.log("result in getIndex: " + result);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    
    getIndex("hello folks and world").done(function(a, b) {
        console.log("done callback arguments: " + a + ", " + b);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown">
  <option>hello folks and others</option>
  <option>hello folks and world</option>
  <option>hello folks and world</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's the point of using a promise with a synchronous operation?  That just complicates otherwise simple code.  `getIndex()` may as well just return the result directly - no promises involved.

Comment: @jfriend00 I took the question to be asking about how to get defered's to work at all,  _using a fabricated example_ . "Hello folks" in a dropdown?